# Randomly assign values with non-overlapping values across rows in data frame

Tags: r, combinatorics

I have a set of 3 reviewers that I want to randomly assign exactly four reviews each across six applicants. My goal is for every application to be read by two unique reviewers.

```r
reviewers <- c("reviewer1", "reviewer2", "reviewer3")

applications <- data.frame(applicant = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
    reviewer1_assigned = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    reviewer2_assigned = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I want to make sure that no reviewer is assigned to the same application twice *and* no reviewer reviews more than two applications. Any ideas how to solve this?

The final data frame should ideally look like this:

```r
> applications
  applicant        reviewer1_assigned reviewer2_assigned
1         1                 reviewer1          reviewer2
2         2                 reviewer3          reviewer2
3         3                 reviewer3          reviewer1
4         4                 reviewer1          reviewer3
5         5                 reviewer2          reviewer1
6         6                 reviewer2          reviewer3
```

It's fine if a pair of reviewers reviews 2 different applications (e.g. applicant 1 is assigned r1+r2, applicant 2 is assigned r2+r1). What I want to avoid is that a single applicant is assigned the same reviewer twice (e.g. applicant 1 being assigned r1+r1).

This is fine:

```r
> applications
  applicant        reviewer1_assigned reviewer2_assigned
1         1                 reviewer1          reviewer2
2         2                 reviewer2          reviewer1
```

This is not:

```
> applications
  applicant        reviewer1_assigned reviewer2_assigned
1         1                 reviewer1          reviewer1
```

I'd also appreciate it if someone has a solution for a case in which the number of applications is not divisible by the number of reviewers (if we take the previous example and expand the applicant pool to 7, let's say every reviewer receives at least 4 assignments and two people receive 5 assignments for 7 applications total).

Comment: *no reviewer reviews more than two applications*. Isn't row 4 *reviewer1* the third use of him?

Comment: You're right, will fix it!

Comment: Still a problem. Now what will row 5 have? ie You only have 4 reviewers. Who will you put in row 5?

Comment: My bad, fixed this issue, too! Now it should all be correct (every reviewer reviews 4 applications and every application has a unique set of reviewers).

Comment: Now you have reviewers reviewing more than two applications, which you didn't want in the original question.

Comment: yes, everyone needs to review 4 applications (I fixed the problem description) and r1+r2 and r2+r1 pair is totally fine - i just need to make sure that reviewer 1 is not assigned to a single applicant twice. I can add that to the problem description though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask for is called (in combinatorics and statistical experimental design) a [**block design**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design).  Your applicants are *treatments* and reviewers are *blocks*.  There is an R package (on CRAN) `blocksdesign`. Using that we get

```r
library(blocksdesign)

blocks(treatments=6, replicates=2, blocks=3)
$Replication
  Treatments freq
1          1    2
2          2    2
3          3    2
4          4    2
5          5    2
6          6    2

$Blocks_model
  Level Blocks D-Efficiency A-Efficiency   A-Bound
1     1      3    0.8913012    0.8823529 0.8823529

$Design
   Level_1 plots treatments
1       B1     1          3
2       B1     2          6
3       B1     3          1
4       B1     4          5
5       B2     5          2
6       B2     6          4
7       B2     7          6
8       B2     8          1
9       B3     9          2
10      B3    10          5
11      B3    11          3
12      B3    12          4

$Plan
  Level_1 Blocks.Plots: 1 2 3 4
1      B1               3 6 1 5
2      B2               2 4 6 1
3      B3               2 5 3 4

$seed
NULL

$searches
[1] 417

$jumps
[1] 1
```

and that should already be randomized.

Comment: Today I learned! This worked for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

An approach, getting the combinations with `expand_grid`, then shuffling the rows with `sample`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(42)

data.frame(applications[1], 
  (expand_grid(reviewer1_assigned = reviewers, reviewer2_assigned = reviewers) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    filter(!any(duplicated(c_across(everything())))) %>% 
    ungroup()
  )[sample(length(reviewers) * 2),])
  applicant reviewer1_assigned reviewer2_assigned
1         1          reviewer1          reviewer2
2         2          reviewer3          reviewer1
3         3          reviewer3          reviewer2
4         4          reviewer2          reviewer3
5         5          reviewer1          reviewer3
6         6          reviewer2          reviewer1
```

About the second question, use one more sampled row, e.g.

```
  (expand_grid(reviewer1_assigned = reviewers, reviewer2_assigned = reviewers) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    filter(!any(duplicated(c_across(everything())))) %>% 
    ungroup()
  )[c(sample(length(reviewers) * 2), 
      sample(length(reviewers) * 2, 1),] # adds one random row of reviewers
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  reviewer1_assigned reviewer2_assigned
  <chr>              <chr>             
1 reviewer3          reviewer2         
2 reviewer1          reviewer3         
3 reviewer2          reviewer3         
4 reviewer3          reviewer1         
5 reviewer2          reviewer1         
6 reviewer1          reviewer2         
7 reviewer2          reviewer3
```

Answer (score 1):

So, with 6 applicants and 4 reviewers it's not possible for each reviewer to only review 2, if each application is being reviewed twice. With four reviewers, each reviewing 2, you'd review 8 applicants. You have 6 applicants each being reviewed twice, or 12 assignments.

Anyway, the dataset being arranged the way you requested makes it hard to ensure your requirements are met, but you could rearrange the resulting dataset from code like this:

```
#assigning variables
reviewers <- c("reviewer1", "reviewer2", "reviewer3", "reviewer4")
applicant = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
no.reviews=2
#number of times to review each applicant^
max.reviews=2
#number of applicants per reviewer^
assignments=data.frame()

for(each in 1:length(applicant)){
#get the available reviewers each iteration
remove = assignments[assignments$assigning %in% 
names(which(table(assignments$assigning) > max.reviews)),2]
reviewers.sub=reviewers[!reviewers %in% remove]

#assign reviewers
assigning=c(sample(reviewers.sub,no.reviews, replace=FALSE))

#make the dataframe
assigned=data.frame(rep(each,no.reviews), assigning)
assignments=rbind(assignments,assigned)}

colnames(assignments)=c("applicant", "reviewer")
```

The resulting dataset gives an error when you start applicant 5 that there are no more reviewers left, if you modify the max.reviews then you  will have some reviewers doing 3 to cover the last two applicants.

Comment: By unique I meant that no applicant should be reviewed by the same reviewer twice - not that every reviewer can only review 2 applications. But I see that I'd need to adjust that for the second part of the question. Thank you for your solution!

Comment: Gotcha. This code would work regardless, since it will not pull the same reviewer twice when sample(data, replace=FALSE). However, without the max.reviews option you may get a random scenario where a reviewer is assigned to all applicants, so it would be beneficial to still set that parameter if you want to ensure even distribution of reviewers.